# Is there a reliable source for clean dry beans?

Tags: beans

When I clean and sort a cup of dry beans it takes a long time and I find myself discarding a good tablespoon of dirt, rocks and beans that don't look right. These are beans purchased in 1 pound packages for prices that seem like great bargains, when compared to canned beans, until I get into the cleaning and sorting again.
I would rather cook from dry than eat canned, but I would also like to start with clean beans. Where can I find them?
I am in Rochester Minnesota, US.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, this is just part of buying dried beans... though I don't usually have this much trash to clean out, nearly every recipe that calls for dried beans tells you to sort through them first.  Anyway, if we're going to even attempt to answer this, you're going to have to tell us where you are... different states/countries/continents have different suppliers and our site is not US-centric, so we don't make assumptions about where people live.

Comment: While every bean package warns that you should look for possible rocks that have made it through the system, I can't recall finding a single one in many years - store brand 1-lb bagged beans or Goya brand (more expensive.) Nor have I had any dirt. The occasional "floater" is easily removed, since it floats. You're evidently finding some considerably lower-quality product than I see in the Northeast USA.

Comment: Catija - thank you. I've added my location to my question. Ecnerwal - thank you. I have seen Goya in one or more stores here. I will try them.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, bagged dry beans (such as Goya brand) tend to require less cleaning than ones purchased in the open, bulk bins at grocery stores.

However, you should still carefully wash them and search for rocks regardless.

Comment: Jon - thank you! I will try Goya next time. Of course I will sort and wash.